# Unable to remove Wine repository

Tags: apt, updates, wine, repository, 22.04

I have tried everything so far that I can find online and I am unable to delete wine key.

I have installed new Ubuntu 22.04 and installed Wine, but it seems like it has trouble updating it via terminal command as it comes with a message:

```
Err:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I assumed that because 22.04 is so new that there is no current release so I will just delete the repository and purge wine completely, but it seems like even after uninstalling wine I am unable to delete this key. I tried going into software & updates and other software and the actual key is not there.

I tried deleting with apt-key del, but get the following message:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

I also tried going to **sudo nano /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d** and the key is not even on the list.

Nothing seems to work so hopefully someone can help me! Much appreciated

Comment: You probably have to delete `/usr/share/keyrings/winehq-archive.key`

Comment: I just checekd the folder and the actual winehq-archive.key is not there, any other suggestions?

Comment: This one here actually shows how to install the key for the winehq version for 22.04.  However, winehq-stable is not available yet for 22.04.  https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-winehq-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/

Comment: That actually fixed the issue, I guess I should have googled more to find a solution, thank you very much!